# How can i change the Effect of slicder from Fade to some other transition without delay jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, jquery-ui, slider

I am using following Slider for the web project I want to change the transition effect of image to different like slide left, slide up etc..

http://demo.webdeveloperplus.com/featured-content-slider/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#featured > ul").tabs({ fx: { opacity: "toggle"} }).tabs("rotate", 4000, true);
});
```

If i change `toggle` to `fast` then it works but ads slight delay of less than a second. I would appreciate if i can fix this and make it work like one on WTA website http://www.wtatennis.com/page/Home/0,,12781,00.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change the effect you can just change `opacity` to `width`, `height`, `show`, etc and you will get different animations.

As far as the speed, you can use "slow", "normal", "fast" OR set a value in milliseconds (in case you want something instant).

Try something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#featured > ul").tabs({ fx: { width: 'toggle', duration: 1000 } }).tabs("rotate", 4000, true);
});​
```